# Jade won't show results of mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I'm using node.js, express, jade and mysql.

```
\\app.js
var db_config = {
host: 'localhost',
port: '3306',
[redacted]
};
var connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
...
app.get('/events', routes.events(connection));  


\\index.js
exports.events = function (db) {
return function (req, res) {

    db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error\'d:', err);
        }
    });

    db.query('SELECT name FROM event', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(rows);
            res.render('events', { "items": rows });
        }
    });
}  


\\events.jade
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        Events List
    ul
    - each event in items
        li = event
```

When I run this, the console shows the results of the query, but jade seems to refuse to go over it.
All the tutorials I can find seem to have near identical code to mine.
I was previously getting an error:

```
5|         Events List
6|     ul
> 7|     - each event in items
8|             li event.name
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

but can't remember what I was doing when that popped up.

Currently console outputs:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
[ { name: 'Test event' },
{ name: 'Test event 2' },
{ name: 'Test event 3' },
{ name: 'Woooh event' } ]
GET /events 200 364ms - 151b
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4ms
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The console shows `rows` as an array as part of the call to your index function?

Comment: Please add the exact console.log results. rows is probably returning as an array that doesn't make sense to go as the value of the items key.

Comment: You need to at least use `li= event.name` to get `event.name` to be expanded, but that's probably not your issue. Are you not overwriting `items` somewhere?

Comment: items is not being used anywhere else. I've tried both `li= event` and `li= event.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted with some help

`li #{event.name}`
and
`res.render('events', { "items": rows });`
instead of
`res.render('events', { "items": JSON.stringify(rows) });`

Answer (score 1):

Try without '-' and use global variable locals:

```
    each event in locals.items
```

Answer (score 0):

check [`JSON.stringify();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

try:

```
else {
    console.log(rows);
    res.render('events', { "items": JSON.stringify(rows)});
    }
```